# How to make textview clickable to an url in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

i want to make a clickable TextView 
that i can put an URL dynamically in

im using it in if statment

so i can change the  URL according to the condition

like : ClickHere and it takes him to the url

return Thanks ;

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textURL"
                    android:text="Click Here"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

ps : i know about the strings way i coudlnt use it cuz i want to add more TextViews for some conditions
and there is a lot

Comment: I think you should using SpanableString and ClickableSpan